# MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

I have an issue perform docker build

```
docker build -t ordering .
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Ordering.API.dll"]
```

Error from the terminal

```
Step 9/15 : RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app
 ---> Running in edb1cdf64b43
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.5.180.51428 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have been google for a while for this issues.
    Please help

Comment: Is it correct path `/src/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API` ? Do you have **src** inside **src**?

Comment: I trying this open source: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers to build one of the services

Comment: Is your DockerFile located at the root of the directory which also contains `src` subdirectory? As @RomanMarusyk mentioned I think `WORKDIR /src/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API` is incorrect. Please try `WORKDIR /src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API`

Comment: @moshin-mehmood I try to change to WORKDIR /src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API didn't work

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The issue fix by using `docker-compose.yml` up

Answer (score -1):

I've only seen that error when attempting to run `dotnet run` with an already published project (which you do seem to be working with an already published project). Instead, you should simply do `dotnet MyProject.dll` (no `run`).

Comment: The error is not on the dotnet run, is on dotnet build, please refer to the error from the terminal